# Agregar botones siguiente/anterior en un Nav-Pills Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, nav

Necesito ayuda para darle función a botones de navegación Siguiente/Anterior en un Nav-Pills horizontal de Bootstrap 4 con Jquery. Esto para crear una especie de form-wizard. He intentado darle funcionalidad a los nav-pills a través de Jquery pero no sé cual es el error, ya que pruebo con nav-tabs verticales y si funciona. Sin embargo, al probar con nav-pills en horizontal, los botones pierden su funcionalidad.

El código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FRM - Gestión de Riesgos Financieros</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
   

  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="container">
            
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            
            
            
                                
                                <br>
                                
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-3">
                                    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">  
                                    
                                     <a class="nav-link nav-item active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                                  
                                     <a class="nav-link nav-item" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                                   
                                    <a class="nav-link nav-item" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
                                     <a class="nav-link nav-item" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-9">
                                    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                                      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                                         <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm previous">Previous</button>
                                          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm next">Next</button></div>
                                      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm previous">Previous</button>
                                          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm next">Next</button></div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">
                                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm previous">Previous</button>
                                          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm next">Next</button></div>
                                          </div>
                                      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">
                                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm previous">Previous</button>
                                          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm next">Next</button></div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
            
                            </div>
                            
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $('.next').click(function () {
                $('.nav-pills > .nav-item > .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
            });
            
            $('.previous').click(function () {
                $('.nav-pills > .nav-item > .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
            });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

No sé en qué estaré fallando pero al agregar lista de navegación `<ul>` y `<li>` se pierde el formato horizontal del nav-pill, por lo que estoy tratando de dar la funcionalidad a los `<a>`

Comment: Revisa tu codigo, has puesto 4 versiones de jQuery en el ejemplo, en ocasiones cuando tienes más de una versión en tu proyecto causas conflictos en el mismo. Saludos.

Comment: Lo edité dejando solo la última versión, sin embargo el problema persiste